# Build table with different cells sizes

Tags: tables, multirow

I have written this code for the table shown bellow on the left but I like to make some modifications so it looks like the table on the right. Can you help me?

```
\begin{table}[t]\footnotesize\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-1pt}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ c || c | c || c | c ||}
\hline
{\bf Types} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\bf Line A} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\bf Line B} \\\hline\hline
 & a  & b & a  & b \\\hline
x & d  & 2 & 76  & 2 \\\hline
y & 1 & 3 & 74 & 3 \\\hline\hline
z & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{4a} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{4a} \\
\hline  
\end{tabular}
\caption{ll}
\label{table:senspec}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please complete your code to a full copy/paste compilable form such that people who would like to help you don't bother with completing your document?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get to the following. It still needs improvement as the borders for first and last row do not align properly with the borders of other rows. Also width of two columns under `Line A` do not match.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| c |@{}c@{\,}| c | c |@{}c@{\,}| c | c |}
    \hline
        \textbf{Types} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Line A}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Line B}} \\
    \hline 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\[-0.9\normalbaselineskip]
    \cline{3-4} \cline{6-7}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & & a  & b & & a  & b \\
    \cline{1-1} \cline{3-4} \cline{6-7}
        x & & d  & 2 & &  76  & 2 \\
    \cline{1-1} \cline{3-4} \cline{6-7}
        y & & 1 & 3 & & 74 & 3 \\
    \cline{1-1} \cline{3-4} \cline{6-7}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\[-0.9\normalbaselineskip]
    \hline
        z & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{4a} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{4a} \\
    \hline  
\end{tabular}

\caption{ll}
\label{table:senspec}   
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @kevin Glad I was able to help, but would suggest using David's solution with `hhline`. It is cleaner because it does not introduce unnecessary column like mine. I would have done it that way if I knew about the `hhline` package.

Answer (score 8):

This is not really an answer to your question, merely a suggestion *and* an answer:

## Notes

- [`\bf` is a bad idea](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/520/16595).
- You can use `\cline{2-3}` to only draw a horizontal line from column 2 to 3.
- The `center` environment adds vertical space (it's a `list`). If you don't want this use `\centering` (like I did in my examples).

## What I would suggest

This takes advantages from the excellent [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package.
There are the following rules when it comes to this package (and others claim this a valid for good style, too):

1. Don't use vertical lines.
2. Obey rule 1.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand{\cmidrulekern}{.25em}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]%\footnotesize%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-1pt}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
    \toprule
    \bfseries Types & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Line A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Line B} \\
    \cmidrule(r){2-3}\cmidrule(l){4-5}
                    & a &                b                 & a  &                b                \\
    \midrule
           x        & d &                2                 & 76 &                2                \\
           y        & 1 &                3                 & 74 &                3                \\
    \cmidrule(r){2-3}\cmidrule(l){4-5} % Maybe don't use these cmidrules.
           z        &        \multicolumn{2}{c}{4a}        &        \multicolumn{2}{c}{4a}        \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{second way}
\label{table:senspec}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

## Kind of what you wanted

The vertical lines between "Types" and "Line A" as well as between "Line A" and "Line B" seem to need a little tweaking.
<sub><sup>**I'm sure someone with more (plain)TeX table experience can help us out here.**</sup></sub>

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]\footnotesize%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-1pt}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|@{\extracolsep{2pt}}c@{\extracolsep{-2pt}}|c|@{\extracolsep{2pt}}c@{\extracolsep{-2pt}}|c|}
\hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\bfseries Types} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Line A} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\bfseries Line B} \\
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\cline{2-3}\cline{4-5}
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{}          & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{a} &                b                 & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{a}  &                 b                 \\
\cline{1-1}\cline{2-3}\cline{4-5}
                      x                   & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{d} &                2                 & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{76} &                 2                 \\
\cline{1-1}\cline{2-3}\cline{4-5}
                      y                   & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1} &                3                 & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{74} &                 3                 \\
\cline{1-1}\cline{2-3}\cline{4-5}
\noalign{\smallskip}
\hline
                      z                   &        \multicolumn{2}{c}{4a}        & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{4a}               \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Prediction Accuracy of the Enose System in Lung Cancer Detection}
\label{table:senspec2}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 8):

[image]

`hhline` can help here (unrelated but never use `\bf` in LaTeX they are not defined at all in the format and only included in the standard classes for compatibility with LaTeX 2.09)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,hhline}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]\footnotesize\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-1pt}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| c || c | c || c | c |}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Types}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Line A}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Line B}} \\
\hline
\noalign{\vskip\doublerulesep}%
\hhline{~--||--}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & a  & b & a  & b \\
\hhline{-||-|-||-|-|}
x & d  & 2 & 76  & 2 \\
\hhline{-||-|-||-|-|}
y & 1 & 3 & 74 & 3 \\
\hhline{:=:b:=:=:b:=:=:}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{z} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{4a} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{4a} \\
\hline  
\end{tabular}
\caption{ll}
\label{table:senspec}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: While researching for an answer I stumbled upon some examples that use (your) `hhline` package but didn't quite get it right. Note to myself: _Read at least the manual's first page._

Comment: The need to have the `\noalign{\vskip` is a defficiency in hhline, it doesn't currently allow you to just have the top half of a double rule across a column (`t` gives you the top section between ||) But otherwise `hhline` was more or less designed fro this kind of table (despite the general adherence to booktabs on this site:-)